# JavaFX animations using loops?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to build a space invaders like game. 
I've drawn a square and I want to move it down incrementally by using a loop and `thread.sleep`. However, the square just gets drawn immediately. I understand there are animation paths that could be used but I want to stay low level and just use a coordinate system.

Is there a way of making a timeline animation by using a loop like this?

```
package com.company;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;

public class Main extends  Application  {

    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        // write your code here
        launch(args);
    }

    public void start(Stage myStage) throws InterruptedException {
        myStage.setTitle("space invaders");

        Pane rootNode= new Pane();
        Scene myScene=new Scene(rootNode, 400, 800);
        myStage.setScene(myScene);
        Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
        myStage.show();
        rootNode.getChildren().add(r);
        r.setX(50);
        r.setY(50);
        r.setWidth(20);
        r.setHeight(20);

        for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++){
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            r.setTranslateY(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you _must not_ sleep on the FX application thread!

Comment: Do I need to multi thread?

Comment: You should take a look at [`AnimationTimer`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/animation/AnimationTimer.html). I know you mentioned you'd like to stay away from the animation API but it's the lowest level of the API and provides a way to "loop" (different from `for` or `while` loops) on the FX thread without blocking the FX thread. Otherwise, you will need to use separate thread and fire updates back to the FX thread using `Platform.runLater`.

Comment: Hiya , yeah problem solved now , managed to get the loop working by using multithreading. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Good place to start. https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/introduction-to-javafx-for-game-development--cms-23835

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a terrible implementation. I would probably use [`AnimationTimer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/AnimationTimer.html). This is done with [`Timeline`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Timeline.html). It's basically moving right or left. If you hit the right or left bound, drop then move in the opposite direction.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.PauseTransition;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class JavaFXApplication343 extends Application
{
    int invaderWidth = 30;
    int invaderHeight = 10;
    int gapBetweenInvaderX = 5;
    int gapBetweenInvaderY = 5;
    int locationTrackerX;
    int locationTrackerY;

    int screenWidth = 300;
    int screenHeight = 400;

    double timeBetweenFrames = .25;

    boolean direction = true;

    Timeline timeline;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        Pane pane = new Pane();

        locationTrackerX = (screenWidth - (invaderWidth * 6 + gapBetweenInvaderX * 5)) / 2;
        locationTrackerY = (screenHeight - (invaderHeight * 6 + gapBetweenInvaderY * 5)) / 7;

        List<Rectangle> invaders = new ArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < 36; i++) {
            Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(locationTrackerX, locationTrackerY, invaderWidth, invaderHeight);
            rectangle.setFill(Color.YELLOW);
            invaders.add(rectangle);
            System.out.println(locationTrackerX);

            locationTrackerX += invaderWidth + gapBetweenInvaderX;
            if ((i + 1) % 6 == 0) {
                locationTrackerX = (screenWidth / 2) - ((invaderWidth * 6 + gapBetweenInvaderX * 5) / 2);
                locationTrackerY += invaderHeight + gapBetweenInvaderY;
            }
        }

        timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(timeBetweenFrames), (event) -> {
            //Check to see if invader hits bounds
            Optional<Rectangle> hitRightOptional = invaders.stream().filter(invader -> invader.getBoundsInLocal().getMaxX() >= pane.getWidth()).findFirst();
            Optional<Rectangle> hitLeftOptional = invaders.stream().filter(invader -> invader.getBoundsInLocal().getMinX() <= 0).findFirst();
            //Move invaders
            if (hitRightOptional.isPresent()) {
                invaders.forEach((tempInvader) -> tempInvader.setY(tempInvader.getY() + 10));
                timeline.stop();
                PauseTransition pause = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(timeBetweenFrames));
                pause.setOnFinished((pauseEvent) -> {
                    invaders.forEach(invader -> invader.setX(invader.getX() - 10));
                    timeline.play();
                });
                pause.play();

                direction = false;
            }
            else if (hitLeftOptional.isPresent()) {
                invaders.forEach((tempInvader) -> tempInvader.setY(tempInvader.getY() + 10));
                timeline.stop();
                PauseTransition pause = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(timeBetweenFrames));
                pause.setOnFinished((pauseEvent) -> {
                    invaders.forEach(invader -> invader.setX(invader.getX() + 10));
                    timeline.play();
                });
                pause.play();

                direction = true;
            }
            else {
                if (direction) {
                    invaders.forEach(invader -> invader.setX(invader.getX() + 10));
                }
                else {
                    invaders.forEach(invader -> invader.setX(invader.getX() - 10));
                }
            }
        }));
        timeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);

        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Start Game");
        btn.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
            timeline.play();
            btn.setDisable(true);
        });

        pane.getChildren().addAll(invaders);
        pane.setPrefSize(screenWidth, screenHeight);

        VBox root = new VBox(pane, new StackPane(btn));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, screenWidth, screenHeight);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score -3):

Solved :

```
       Task task = new Task<Void>() {
        @Override public Void call() throws InterruptedException {

            for (int i = 1; i <= 800; i=i+10) {
                Thread.sleep(25);
                //updateProgress(i, max);
                r.setTranslateY(i);
            }
            return null;
        }
    };
    new Thread(task).start();
```

Comment: Why do you insist on doing it the wrong way? Use the AnimationTimer and you are done (correctly). An AnimationTimer basically just does the looping for you and you just specify the code that you normally find inside your for-loop. What's so difficult about that?

Comment: wrong wrong wrong ... you still change node's state off the FX app thread